# "ESLint": ... is not defined - Knockoutjs and google maps

Tags: google-maps, knockout.js, eslint

I am using ESLint to lint my JavaScript. I am also using Knockout.js and Google Maps. The problem I ran into is ESLint doesn't recognize the `google` and `ko` variables.

My first attempt was to [specify environments](http://eslint.org/docs/user-guide/configuring.html#specifying-environments) but I realized (after reading the documentation and crashing eslint) that the list provided by the documentation is exclusive.

Then I tried [specifying globals](http://eslint.org/docs/user-guide/configuring.html#specifying-globals) but no luck there as well.

So my question is, how can I make it so ESLint recognizes my Google Maps library and Knockout.js?

Comment: What have you tried? It should be enough to declare google and ko as global variables as in the link you provided.

Comment: @henmer Thanks for taking the time :) Regarding the global variables, I put the `"globals"` into `"eslintConfig"` which was inside my `package.json`. Maybe that's why it didn't work?

Answer (score 0):

Defining globals in .eslintrc.js should work. The following is an example that supports jQuery `$`, Google (`google`, custom site search in our case), and Knockout.js (`ko`).

```
module.exports = {
    root: true,
    extends: [
        'eslint:recommended'
    ],
    env: {
        "browser": true,
        "commonjs": true,
        "jquery": true
    },
    globals: {
        "google": true,
        "ko": true
    }
};
```